# Is there any way to get Selenium to print off the target page to a printer?

Tags: selenium

I've looked everywhere and tried all possible ways. Just asking if anyone else has found a way to print?
Thanks

Comment: Your best would probably be to just take a screenshot and then print that instead of trying to do it through the driver (I'm 99% sure you won't be able to print through the driver anyways)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible ways:

1. Use JavaScript's [`window.print()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.print) + [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) (pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to confirm the dialog.
2. Get a screenshot and [print it](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/printing/). [PrinterJob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html).